# What's the point of using random strings for classes or ids in HTML?

Tags: html, css-selectors

I was browsing some pages and saw the really strange thing in the class names or ids of the elements.

Some of the examples could be:

1. Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/
   [image]

   2. Gmail: https://gmail.com
      [image]

I know this question is a little bit silly but when I'm coding I want to make sure each of the class corresponds the purpose of that element. Sorry if this was answered before, however, I couldn't find it.

Why do these companies (and many more) use this method of selecting elements?

Comment: Probably to make it harder for bots to scrape the content. Or it's an artefact of some internal compilation process. Probably both.

Comment: But the class names remain the same after I reload the page so the bot creator could easily associate these random strings with elements. Should I use this technique, too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com doesn't use this, though.

Comment: Those elements are probably generated in some kind of website builder, they make random ids and classes and add the styling properties specific to that element in css using those ids and classes

Comment: I see these types of things only in the modern companies' websites.

Comment: Normally html is generated once and stored, so no matter how many times you request the page you will get same ids. They are not generated on runtime, which makes the loading of page too slow

Comment: In a nutshell: they do not write their HTML by hand, they have some abstract backend system which generates the HTML and associated CSS automatically. Otherwise the complexity, especially in the case of Google, would probably be unmanageable.

Comment: In your own code it's recommended to use easy to understand classes/IDs/... If you compile into weirdness that's fine as long as your source code can be maintained and understood

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for the answers :)